# pyinstaller import error, no image found

Tags: macos, python-2.7, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make an application for a mac.   When I use pyinstaller to make an exe on a windows machine, it works fine, but when I do it on a mac, the file complies, but then when executed I get the following errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/build/new_client/out00-PYZ.pyz/FileDialog", line 11, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/build/new_client/out00-PYZ.pyz/Tkinter", line 39, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 409, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
ImportError: dlopen(/var/folders/vb/vb9xryxdEz467ZADn0LL7U+++TI/-Tmp-/_MEIbvFCo2/_tkinter.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/Tcl
  Referenced from: /var/folders/vb/vb9xryxdEz467ZADn0LL7U+++TI/-Tmp-/_MEIbvFCo2/_tkinter.so
  Reason: image not found
```

It appears to be something wrong with Tkinter and TCL.  Here are the modules that are loaded by the program.

```
import socket, thread, time, json, traceback, FileDialog
from functools import partial
from mtTkinter import *
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using openpyxl and it required jdcal in the datetime.py module. None of the hidden imports or any of those pyinstaller work-arounds helped, running the exe would still say jdcal not found. The work-around that I used was to just copy the few functions from jdcal directly into the datetime.py in the openpyxl code. Then ran pyinstaller -F program.py

and it worked!  Not the best answer, but when you are trying to get a project out the door for a client, it works.